# How do I update translated text when changing a language in a Vue.js app with i18n and Pinia?

Tags: vue.js, quasar, pinia, vue-i18n

I'm using i18n and Pinia to try to change languages in my application, but when I change the language, only the value of `localStorage.language` changes, but the text doesn't. I tried to make the change using [pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/getting-started.html) to "force" a re-render, but it didn't work either. I would like to know how I can do this because although the value of `localStorage.language` does change, the application doesn't re-render.

This is my language store:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useLanguageStore = defineStore('languages', {
  store: () => {
    return {
      language: 'es',
    }
  },
  actions: {
    setNewLanguage({ newLanguage } = {}) {
      if (!localStorage.language) {
        this.language = newLanguage ?? 'es'
        localStorage.setItem('language', this.language)
      }
    }
  },
})
```

This is the i18n.js:

```
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
import messages from '@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n/messages'

import pinia from '../stores'

export const i18n = createI18n({
  legacy: false,
  globalInjection: true,
  locale: localStorage.language,
  fallbackLocale: 'es',
  availableLocales: ['de', 'en', 'es', 'ja', 'pt', 'ru', 'zh'],
  messages: messages
});
```

And this is my main.js (in case it's necessary):

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { Quasar } from 'quasar'
import quasarLang from 'quasar/lang/es'
import router from './routes/router.js'
import { createPinia, PiniaVuePlugin } from 'pinia'

// Import icon libraries
import '@quasar/extras/material-icons/material-icons.css'
import '@quasar/extras/material-icons-outlined/material-icons-outlined.css'
import '@quasar/extras/material-icons-round/material-icons-round.css'
import '@quasar/extras/material-icons-sharp/material-icons-sharp.css'

// A few examples for animations from Animate.css:
import '@quasar/extras/animate/fadeIn.css'
import '@quasar/extras/animate/fadeOut.css'

// Import Quasar css
import 'quasar/src/css/index.sass'

import { i18n } from './utils/i18n.js'

import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App)
.use(createPinia())
.use(Quasar, {
  plugins: {}, // import Quasar plugins and add here
  lang: quasarLang,
})
.use(router)
.use(i18n)
.mount('#app')
```

I have left the repository public for more information (clearly, it has the latest changes); anyway, I haven't started the actual development yet, so there shouldn't be a problem: https://github.com/Santiago1010/idi-front

Comment: `locale: localStorage.language` is a mistake. It's not guaranteed to exist, especially since Quasar is SSR , and you don't have a fallback value. You don't update i18n locale in setNewLanguage, and you likely should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting the i18n locale when you try to switch the language in your `setNewLanguage` function. You only update localStorage, but localStorage is not reactive.

You should import i18n in your Pinia store:

```
import { i18n } from './utils/i18n.js';
```

And set the global locale in your `setNewLanguage` function:

```
i18n.locale = ‘es’;
```

See i18n docs: https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/essentials/scope.html#locale-changing

Comment: I genuinely appreciate the time and effort you took to understand my problem and provide a clear and concise solution. Your expertise and knowledge in the field are truly commendable. Not only did you address my concerns effectively, but you also offered additional insights that have expanded my understanding of the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Saving the current locale in the Pinia store is not required to change the language. I18n and Quasar itself store necessary data.

However, locale storage comes in handy after reloading the page. You will be able to restore the last state at app startup.

Quasar uses [standard names](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/tree/dev/ui/lang) for locales of its internal components and system (`en-GB` instead of `en`). For example, `q-table` is expected to show `No result` according to the current language. I strongly recommend you use names instead of short ones to preserve the harmony.

#### Implementation

First rename `src/locales/en.json` to `src/locales/en-GB.json`, and also, `src/locales/zh.json` to `src/locales/zh-CN.json`.

Changing the locale will be easy if you use the names. To exercise, your code can be something like this:

```js
<template>
  <q-btn color="secondary" :label="$t('changeLanguage')">
    <q-menu auto-close>
      <q-list style="min-width: 100px">
        <q-item v-for="(language, index) in languages" @click="changeLanguage(index)" clickable>
          <q-item-section>{{ language }}</q-item-section>
        </q-item>
      </q-list>
    </q-menu>
  </q-btn>
</template>

<script setup>
// Importar internos de vue
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { useQuasar } from 'quasar';
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n';

const $q = useQuasar();
const i18n = useI18n({useScope: 'global'});

import deQ from 'quasar/lang/de';
import enQ from 'quasar/lang/en-GB';
import esQ from 'quasar/lang/es';
import jaQ from 'quasar/lang/ja';
import ptQ from 'quasar/lang/pt';
import ruQ from 'quasar/lang/ru';
import zhQ from 'quasar/lang/zh-CN';

const langPacks = {
  de: deQ,
  'en-GB': enQ,
  es: esQ,
  ja: jaQ,
  pt: ptQ,
  ru: ruQ,
  'zh-CN': zhQ,
};

// Constantes y variables del componente
const languages = ref({
  'de': ' Deutsch',
  'en-GB': ' English',
  'es': ' Español',
  'ja': ' 日本語',
  'pt': ' Português',
  'ru': ' Русский',
  'zh-CN': ' 中文',
});


// Funciones y métodos
function changeLanguage(newLanguage) {
  i18n.locale.value = newLanguage;
  $q.lang.set(langPacks[newLanguage]);
  localStorage.setItem('language', newLanguage);
}
</script>
```

##### Note 1:

In this case, there is no need for the Pinia store anymore. You can remove it safely. If you need to detect the current locale, you can use `$q.lang.isoName`.

#### Using composition

Add a new composition file to manage the state and provides the necessary actions to change and restore locales.

```js
// src/composable/use-locale-switcher.js

import { ref } from 'vue';
import { useQuasar } from 'quasar';
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n';

import deQ from 'quasar/lang/de';
import enQ from 'quasar/lang/en-GB';
import esQ from 'quasar/lang/es';
import jaQ from 'quasar/lang/ja';
import ptQ from 'quasar/lang/pt';
import ruQ from 'quasar/lang/ru';
import zhQ from 'quasar/lang/zh-CN';

const langPacks = {
  de: deQ,
  'en-GB': enQ,
  es: esQ,
  ja: jaQ,
  pt: ptQ,
  ru: ruQ,
  'zh-CN': zhQ,
};

export function useLocaleSwitcher() {
  const locale = ref('es');

  const $q = useQuasar();
  const i18n = useI18n({useScope: 'global'});

  function setLocale(lang) {
    locale.value = lang;
    i18n.locale.value = lang;
    $q.lang.set(langPacks[lang]);
    localStorage.setItem('language', lang);
  }

  function loadLastState(name) {
    const prevState = localStorage.getItem('language');
    setLocale(prevState || 'es');
  }

  return {
    locale,
    setLocale,
    loadLastState,
  };
}
```

Your lang switcher will be:

```js
// src/components/ChangeLanguage
<template>
  <q-btn color="secondary" :label="$t('changeLanguage')">
    <q-menu auto-close>
      <q-list style="min-width: 100px">
        <q-item v-for="(language, index) in languages" @click="changeLanguage(index)" clickable>
          <q-item-section>{{ language }}</q-item-section>
        </q-item>
      </q-list>
    </q-menu>
  </q-btn>
</template>

<script setup>
// Importar internos de vue
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { useLocaleSwitcher } from '../composable/use-locale-switcher.js';

const localeSwitcher = useLocaleSwitcher();

// Constantes y variables del componente
const languages = ref({
  'de': ' Deutsch',
  'en-GB': ' English',
  'es': ' Español',
  'ja': ' 日本語',
  'pt': ' Português',
  'ru': ' Русский',
  'zh-CN': ' 中文',
});


// Funciones y métodos
function changeLanguage(newLanguage) {
  localeSwitcher.setLocale(newLanguage);
}
</script>
```

And tune the app main file to restore state:

```js
// src/App.vue
<template>
  <router-view/>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useLocaleSwitcher } from './composable/use-locale-switcher.js';

const localeSwitcher = useLocaleSwitcher();
localeSwitcher.loadLastState();
</script>
```

##### Further:

For more information please visit [the documentation](https://quasar.dev/options/app-internationalization).